# Create login function for React-native app

Tags: node.js, sql-server, react-native

I'm trying to make a login function for a react-native app. I have created restful api with Nodejs, use SQL Server for database and tested with Postman, it's successful. But when I fetch to URL of server, and I send username and pass from UI (I'm running the app on my phone device, not emulator), I receive

> [TypeError: Network request failed].

Can anyone help me, please? Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView  } from 'react-native';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';

const Login = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const onSubmitHandler = () => {
        const data = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        };

        console.log(data)

        fetch('http://10.7.165.91:8090/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseData => {
                console.log(responseData);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
    return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}> LOGIN </Text>

            <TextInput
                mode="outlined"
                label='username'
                style={styles.input}
                value={username}
                onChangeText={text => setUsername(text)}
            />
            <TextInput
                mode="outlined"
                label="password"
                secureTextEntry
                style={styles.input}
                value={password}
                onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
                right={<TextInput.Icon icon="eye" />}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onSubmitHandler}>
                <Text>Submit</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginBottom: 20,        
    },
    input: {
        marginLeft: 15,
        marginRight: 15,
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 15,
        width: '80%'
    },
    button: {
        elevation: 8,
        backgroundColor: "#009688",
        borderRadius: 50,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 12,
        alignItems: 'center',
        margin: 5
    }
});

export default Login
```

Comment: Is your phone using wifi on the same network as your computer? Or is it using cellular connectivity (3G/4G/5G) instead? The `10.0.0.0/8` address block is a non-routable private network so your cellular carrier won't be routing traffic for it outside of their own network.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I've been wrong about ip address. It should be 192.168.x.x depend on my country.

Comment: That's doesn't really change the connectivity question, I'm afraid. The `192.168.0.0/16` address block is another non-routable private network.